# Fastest way to read 5million row plus of sorted structured data

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, time-series

i need to optimize database for high volume insert/reads

i have a postgress table raw data around 9million row.

Row composed of 2 columns: `timestamp`, `string value`; **data is sorted asc by time**

The only query I use agains this csv is:

```
select * where unixtimestamp between 1600000 and 1700000
```

after getting the data from raw table, i apply some function on result. and cache processed data into another table for faster future queries

I tried mongo with timeseries collection it was better yet still ~ 25sec to fetch; and insert is even longer.

Postgress was best fetch time: but trying to insert 500k row at once would take forever.

So far best way I found was to parse csv files as strings and use binary search to select rows

I think my indexs are not right and that's main problem

So what are your suggestions for keeping maintaining timeseries data where only operation I need is to get in range

**clarify question EDIT1:**

- i have raw data of 9mil rows.
- user can request data from api using one of 20+ aggregation formula
  example `api/get?formula=1&from=2019&to=2021`
- so i check if i do have cache for `formula=1` within this date range
- if not, then i need to load raw data for this date range, apply the formula then the user requested (result is usually 1k row for every 1mill or raw data) then i cache aggregated data for subsequent requests.

i cannot pre-process then data for all formulas in system; because i have over 2000 sensor (each has its own 9mil raw data); result will be more than 2TB of space.

Comment: With these kinds of performance constraints, I think you should consider an in-memory data store, with possible offline backup.

Comment: I fail to understand if the issue is about the amount of time it takes to **load** the data in the database, or the query performance to **retrieve** data from it. How often do you want to load data? How many rows do you expect your query to retrieve each time?

Comment: See also https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/

Comment: You need to use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html) for the import.

Comment: @TheImpaler i retrieve data not so often, bcause this table contain raw log, once user request certain date range i cache aggregated data in other table (its an json api, used by dashboard ui to draw charts) . but some times user ask for aggregation criteria that is not yet cached to then i have to query from raw for ~500k row to process it and cache

Comment: You can write the cached data in another task after returning the JSON result to the user; throughput is the same but latencies for users no longer depend on db write performance.